# Using ORDER BY and FIELD function to get single value to each custom list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table named `orders` having 2 columns `orderNumber` & `status` as follow :

```
orderNumber | status
----------------------------
10100       |   Shipped     |
10101       |   Resolved    |
10102       |   Shipped     |
10103       |   Resolved    |
10104       |   Cancelled   |
10105       |   Shipped     |
10106       |   Cancelled   |
10107       |   Disputed    |
10108       |   In Process  |
10109       |   Cancelled   |
```

I want to get single status with order number order by custom list like this:

```
orderNumber | status
----------------------------
10108       |   In Process  |
10104       |   Cancelled   |
10101       |   Resolved    |
10107       |   Disputed    |
10100       |   Shipped     |
```

I have try this query for that:

```
SELECT orderNumber, status 
FROM orders 
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Cancelled', 'Resolved', 'Disputed', 'Shipped')
```

But this give me all sorted result.

Comment: What defines which `orderNumber` should be in the output?

Comment: Why are you using field values inside your ORDER BY FIELD ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to group by `status`, selecting the minimum `orderNumber` for each `status` value, and then sort according to your `FIELD` expression. You can do that with this query:

```
SELECT MIN(orderNumber) AS orderNumber, status
FROM orders
GROUP BY status
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'In Process', 'On Hold', 'Cancelled', 'Resolved', 'Disputed', 'Shipped')
```

Output:

```
orderNumber     status
10108           In Process
10104           Cancelled
10101           Resolved
10107           Disputed
10100           Shipped
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qcZUPG73ZmwY3cuUdgBd9w/0)

Comment: One more query:
1. How to get random order of orderNumber?
2. How to get same result when orderNumber is string?

Comment: @AnkurMishra I'm not sure what you mean by 1. For 2, the query should work fine even if the orderNumber is string if they are all 5 characters long as MIN will still work in that case.